# Cannot upload user profile photos rails 5 (without gems)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to upload user photos in the user show page, relatively new to rails project.  I'm going to include my users show html erb page, as well as my user controllers and user model, along with what the server is doing when I press the "update" button.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :index]


    def create 
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        if @user.save
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
            redirect_to root_path, notice: "User successfully created."
        else
            redirect_to new_user_path, notice: "Something went wrong, please try again."
        end
    end
    def index
    end

    def update
        if current_user != @user_id
            flash[:notice] = "You cannot update this user"
        end
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
          flash[:notice] = "Profile updated"
          redirect_to @user
        else
          flash[:notice] = "Not uploaded"
          redirect_to @user
        end
    end

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @posts = @user.posts
    end

    def destroy
        if current_user == @user
            @user.destroy
        else
            render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    private
        def user_params
            params.permit(:username, :password, :photo)
        end
end
```

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_token :api_token
    has_secure_password
    validates :username, uniqueness: true
    validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_one_attached :photo
end
```

Users show.html.erb page

```
    <h1 class='h3 mt-5 mb-3 font-weight-normal text-center'><%= @user.username %>  </h1>

<% if notice %>
<p><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>


<% if @user.photo.attached? %>
  <p>
    <strong> Profile Photo </strong>
      <%= image_tag @user.photo, style: "max-width: 100px, max-height: 100px"  %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<div class="text-center">
<p> Upload a profile photo: </p>
  <%= form_with model: @user, local:true do |form| %>
    <%= form.label :photo %>
    <%= form.file_field :photo %>
    <%= form.submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div>
<%= link_to 'Back', root_path %>
</div>

<div>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="card border-secondary text-center" style="width: 30rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">
          <%= post.question %>
          </h3>
        </div>
          <p class="card-text">
          <%= post.body %>
          </p>
          <p class="card-text">
          <%= link_to 'Show', post_path(post) %>
          </p>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

Lastly the server when I hit submit.

```
Started GET "/users/180" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-17 14:45:03 -0400
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"180"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 180], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:18
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 180], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:37
  Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id", 180], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "photo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/users/show.html.erb:8
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 180]]
  ↳ app/views/users/show.html.erb:28
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (4.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 36.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

I know that it is hitting the update method in my userscontroller because the notice is flashing of "Not Uploaded", but the server log seems to suggest it's doing a get request instead of a put?  I would like to achieve this without any gems.

Comment: I believe that is the log that appeared when the  `show.html.erb` is loaded. Can you check once again by submiting the form.

Comment: Yup I checked again, that's what the server is doing upon hitting submit.

Comment: Totally weird. If thats so, I wonder where is the `params` hash from the form

Comment: Got it working!  Please close

Comment: Great! Go ahead and post an answer so that it will help someone in the future.

Comment: The solution was:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the changes in the bold:

```
def update
        if current_user.id != @user_id
            flash[:notice] = "You cannot update this user"
        end
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        **if @user.photo.attach(user_params[:photo])**
          flash[:notice] = "Profile updated"
          redirect_to @user

        else
          flash[:notice] = "Not uploaded"
          redirect_to @user

        end
end
```

And comment_params adjusted to:

```
        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :photo, 
            :email)
        end
```